# Migrations: change column from integer to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can anyone show me how to edit the following migration to change `:phone` integer to string?

```
class CreateContactInfos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :contact_infos do |t|
      t.integer :phone
      t.string :facebook
      t.references :user

      t.timestamps 
    end
    add_index :contact_infos, :user_id
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I guess you already migrated the one you're showing, so create another in which you'd put:

```
change_column :contact_infos, :phone, :string
```

Comment: Should be `:string`, not `:text` which is meant for text over 255 chars, unless you plan on storing really long phone numbers.

Answer (score 3):

I have added some more explanation to this.We need to generate a new migration

`rails g migration change_phone_to_be_string_in_contact_infos`

If we open up the migration we should see something like this

```
class ChangePhoneToBeStringInContactInfos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
 def change
 end
end
```

What we call this migration will have no impact on what we need to do next, but future we and other developers will thank us for naming our migration appropriately.

As you can see the change method is sitting empty. We need to manually add some code here.

```
class ChangePhoneToBeStringInContactInfos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
 def change
  change_column :customers, :phone, :string
 end
end
```

After Saving this file just do rake db:migrate we can see changes we want.

Answer (score 2):

For a reversible migration, use:

```
def up
  change_column :contact_infos, :phone, :string
end

def down
  change_column :contact_infos, :phone, :integer, using: "phone::integer"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert column type string into integer in rails migration :

```
def change
  change_column :contact_infos, :phone, :integer, using: 'phone::integer'
end
```

Convert column type integer into string in rails migration:

```
 def change
   change_column :contact_infos, :phone, :string, using: 'phone::string'
 end
```